# looping and ordering extracted data in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I have hundreds of data files, named file001~file400 for example, and should pick a numeric value from each. I know how to pick each number, but, since there are too many files, I need to loop the command and order all extracted numbers with regard to the number of corresponding file. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is to loop over all files. This can be done in the following way:

```
for i = 1:400
    filename = sprintf('file%03d',i);
    // do the number picking, etc. using the filename.
end
```

EDIT: Per request, for filenames `FT00100` to `FT05320`, we we make two small changes, one in the loop range and one in the first parameter to `sprintf`:

```
for i = 100:5320
    filename = sprintf('FT%05d',i);
    // do the number picking, etc. using the filename.
end
```

Comment: Would you give the solution again assuming the file names are FT00100~FT05320 ?

Comment: I fixed it. Just change loop range and 1st argument to `sprintf`.

Comment: Thanks riklund. For some unknown reason it does not work for me!